# TypeError: <class 'cftime._cftime.Datetime360Day'> is not convertible to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm aware similar questions to this have been asked, but none of the previous solutions work for me.

I have a series of dates which are formatted as:

```
df['time']
0          2010-01-16 00:00:00
1          2010-01-16 00:00:00
2          2010-01-16 00:00:00
3          2010-01-16 00:00:00
4          2010-01-16 00:00:00
```

These have a 360 day calendar.

I'm wanting to convert them to a datetime object in pandas with:

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%Y-%m-%d'
```

I'm only interested in the date, not the time. However, because the calendar is 360 days I just get the error message
`"TypeError: <class 'cftime._cftime.Datetime360Day'> is not convertible to datetime".` I'm aware that cftime does not support the 360 day calendar, so I need a manual way of extracting the date, but every method I've tried to do this fails on the basis that the input is a "cftme._cftime.Datetime360Day" object and not a string.

Does anyone have any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following solution?

You can use *apply* function.

Then, if the type of the column is not *datetime*, you can change it

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def convert_to_dt(x):
    return dt.strptime(str(x), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

df['time'] = df.time.apply(convert_to_dt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not familiar with apply, running that code gives me a NameError.

NameError: name 'convert_to_dt' is not defined

Comment: I made an error copying the function_name :) I gonna edit the post

Comment: Okay, that gave a value error but it can be fixed by including the time data. Line should read: return dt.strptime(str(x),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').  If you can update the answer I'll accept it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am happy to know that it helps you, I approve your comment merge request.

Do not hesitate to check the python **datetime** package.
You can also check the python **dateutil.relativedelta** package to compute timedelta