# How to convert cftime.Datetime360Day to normal datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, netcdf

I have an exported csv file that contains extracted climate data from netCDF file, however the Date column has exported as below list, I would like to change this column to normal datetime.
Is there any solution please!
Thanks!

```
(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 2, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 4, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 7, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)

(cftime.Datetime360Day(2006, 1, 8, 12, 0, 0, 0, has_year_zero=True),)
```

I would like to change this column to normal datetime.
Is there any solution please!
Thanks!

Comment: related: https://github.com/Unidata/cftime/issues/111

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: <class 'cftime.\_cftime.Datetime360Day'> is not convertible to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69841832/typeerror-class-cftime-cftime-datetime360day-is-not-convertible-to-datetim)

Comment: You can do like this:`import datetime;datesout = [datetime.datetime(vv.year,vv.month,vv.day) for vv in datesin]` and datesin has to be the list/array of your `cftime.Datetime360Day` values.

Comment: This will include the 30th of February, which obviously isn't a real date. Do you want to spread the 360 dates over the year or match up day of year in the 360 day calendar to day of year in a standard calendar, i.e. only have the first 360 days of the year in the output?

Answer (score 0):

Datetime360Day is a calendar with every year being 360 days long (divided into 30 day months)

Generally (in around all languages) if there is no means that can help you to do the conversion natively :

You have to use the datetime api and format a string coming from the calendar output.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose that your netcdf4 time data goes from 1970-01-01 to 2005-12-30 & calendar is a 360_day. You also wish to convert to gregorian calendar.

```
    import xarray as xr

    ds = xr.open_dataset('../foo.nc', engine = 'netcdf4', 
    decode_cf=False)

    times = xr.cftime_range(start = '1970-01-01', end = '2005-12- 
    31', calendar = '360_day')
    ds['time'] = times
    
    # Perform calendar correction & convert to datetime64 format        
     ds_standard = ds.convert_calendar(calendar = 'gregorian', 
     align_on = 'date', missing = -99)
```

You should check if the missing dates and non existing dates where added and dropped.
You can read more about xarray.Dataset.convert_calendar() here: https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.convert_calendar.html

Answer (score -1):

I assume you've tried pandas `pd.to_datetime()` already, right?

If not, give that a shot. It generally works really well.

Comment: Pandas does not support this file format and will give you an error